# Scala - Create Set of all possible strings minus one cut letter from word

Tags: scala, collections

I'm still learning scala. If I have one word

```
val word = "abcd"
```

I would like to create

```
Map("bcd","acd","abd","abc")
```

By far I tried:

```
  println(word.map(word.split(_).foldLeft("")(_+_)))
```

but it fails if I have duplicated char in the word.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> def foo(str:String)=(0 until str.length).map(i=>str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1))
foo: (str: String)scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String]

scala> foo("abcd")
res28: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(bcd, acd, abd, abc)
```

Answer (score 8):

It's not necessarily the most efficient approach, but you can do this pretty cleanly with the `inits` and `tails` methods, without any need for dealing with indices, which are arguably "less functional":

```
scala> val word = "abcd"
word: String = abcd

scala> (word.inits.toList.tail.reverse zip word.tails.toList.tail).map {
     |   case (x, y) => x + y
     | }
res0: List[String] = List(bcd, acd, abd, abc)
```

It will work as expected with duplicates.

To see how it works, consider the following:

```
scala> word.inits foreach println
abcd
abc
ab
a


scala> word.tails foreach println
abcd
bcd
cd
d
```

From there it's just a matter of fitting the two together to get the desired result.

---

The following is a more advanced solution that uses the [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) library's implementation of [*zippers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29), which provide a very clean way to approach this problem:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

"abcd".toList.toZipper.map(
  _.cobind(z => (z.lefts.reverse ++ z.rights).mkString).toList
)
```

This will return `Some(List(bcd, acd, abd, abc))`, where the optional wrapper represents the fact that an empty zipper doesn't make sense. In fact you might want to model your solution the same way (if you plan to make it more general), since "leaving one out" of the empty string also doesn't make sense.

If you don't care, and just want the empty string to result in an empty list, you could append `getOrElse Nil` here.

Comment: An alternative to appending `getOrElse Nil` would be to swap the `map` for `foldMap` :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use the additional methods Scala provides on the String object:

```
val word = "abcd"
word.combinations(3).toList
```

Or if you want to remove duplicate characters:

```
word.distinct.combinations(3).toList
```

**Update after comment**
If you want to remove the duplicates use the second example I gave above. To be completely accurate for your example:

```
val word = "abca"
word.distinct.combinations(word.distinct.length-1).toList
```

This returns

```
  res3: List[String] = List(ab, ac, bc)
```

Comment: If my word is "abca" then your code gives me "List(aab, aac, abc)" and this is not what I wanted. I need List(bcd,acd,abd,abc)

Comment: @danny.lesnik If your word is "abca" then you cannot have 'd' in the results.

Answer (score 1):

The collections library is the best place to turn for these things:

```
 def characterCombinations(word: String) = word
   .distinct.combinations(word.distinct.length - 1).toList
 characterCombinations("abcdaaaaaa") // outputs List(abc, abd, acd, bcd)
```

The word is implicitly convertible to an `IndexedSeq[Char]` which has the usual collections methods -- `distinct` removes duplicates in the collection, `combinations(n)` iterates over the combinations of `n` length in the collection, `length` gives you the length of the collection, and `toList` converts the `Iterator[String]` into a `List[String]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution:

```
val word = "abcd" 
(0 to 3) map (i => word.split(word(i)).foldLeft("")(_+_))
```